# Dynamodb import from s3 using emr

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, emr, data-pipeline

I am trying to load json data from s3 bucket to dynamodb using emr. I uploaded data successfully but my count is mismatching without throwing any error.

Why could that happen?

Comment: Could happen because of various reasons. Make sure you are using  updated DynamoDB connector JAR's and I recommend you to look at counters in job history logs to get more info.

Comment: Also can happen if speculation execution is turned-on on Hadoop end. You also need to check if any other writes coming in on that table. BTW, all the implementation  is now open source  https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector